# Can I silence pdfpages output?

Tags: warnings, pdfpages, logging

The `pdfpages` package does not seem to have either a `verbose` or `quiet` option. I am compiling a big document and the include messages from `pdfpages` are obscuring the warnings from other places in the document. Is there a way to quiet these messages or another method for drawing my attention to the warnings?

Comment: What do these messages look like? Please post a piece from your `.log` file.

Comment: AdamTindaleCV.pdf, id=273, page=1, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>
        <use AdamTindaleCV.pdf, page 1> <use AdamTindaleCV.pdf, page 1>
        <use AdamTindaleCV.pdf, page 1> <use AdamTindaleCV.pdf, page 1>
        <use AdamTindaleCV.pdf, page 1> [16 <./AdamTindaleCV.pdf>]
        <AdamTindaleCV.pdf, id=312, page=2, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>

The file is about 300 pages, so there are a lot of these messages. Maybe I should just be grepping the log file for warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can subdue the spew. Here's what is at work...

Essentially [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) uses [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (which in turn uses [`graphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics)) to insert PDF pages. And, all graphics-related error/warning/info and log messages are displayed using four macros:

```
\def\GPT@error{\@PackageError{pdftex.def}}%
\def\GPT@warn{\@PackageWarning{pdftex.def}}%
\ifx\Gin@log\@undefined
  \def\Gin@log{\message}%
\fi
\def\GPT@info{\@PackageInfoNoLine{pdftex.def}}%
```

You could give `pdfpages` the silent treatment by adding

```
\makeatletter
% From pdftex.def
\let\GPT@error\@gobble
\let\GPT@warn\@gobble
\let\Gin@log\@gobble
\let\GPT@info\@gobble
% From latex.ltx
\def\@providesfile#1[#2]{%
  %\wlog{File: #1 #2}% <--- remove writing to .log
  \@addtofilelist{ #2}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The above redefines the output messaging components to gobble their arguments, except for `\@providefile`, for which it only turns off the `.log` writing component. You may not be interested in redefining the error/warning output.

However, this removes *all* graphics-related error/display messaging. Of course, it would be possible to perform this selectively by momentarily switching things off specifically for `\includepdf`.

Comment: This does suppress the output but now I receive this error. ! Package hyperref Error: This should not happen!
(hyperref)                Missing version of `hpdftex.def'.

Comment: @AdamTindale: A minimal document using the above + [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) doesn't produce this error. Could you provide more detail so one can reproduce the problem?

Comment: the problem was that I included that snippet in the wrong place. Once I put after including hyperref the problem disappeared.